# what does it mean when git svn clone runs for a long time, completes, and accomplishes nothing

Tags: git, git-svn

I upgraded git on my mac to 1.7.2. I can no longer get git svn clone or git svn fetch to succeed.

With GIT_TRACE=2, the last words on the subject are:

```
trace: built-in: git 'config' 'svn-remote.svn.branches-maxRev' '12912' 
trace: built-in: git 'config' 'svn-remote.svn.tags-maxRev' '12912'
trace: built-in: git 'config' 'svn-remote.svn.branches-maxRev' '12912' 
trace: built-in: git 'config' 'svn-remote.svn.tags-maxRev' '12912'
trace: built-in: git 'gc' '--auto'
```

git branch -a has nothing to say, nothing is checked out. But no error messages, either.

```
git svn clone -s https://gate.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/gate
```

In case someone else care to try this.

I suppose I should ask a question: "Anyone know a way around this?"

**EDIT**

There is a bug here, but it's completely different from what I claimed. I doubt it has anything to do with the git version.

The URL above is **not** a stdlayout svn url. If you add another /gate to the end, you will be looking at a stdlayout url. The bug is that git svn should be printing a message to the effect that it cannot find trunk, tags, *or* branches.

Comment: Try downloading the source distribution and running the test suite - if it fails, upstream would be very interested to know

Comment: Thanks for the warning! I will not be hasty to upgrade.

Comment: What happened to this one? I'm having the excact same result.

Comment: did you read the 'EDIT'?

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw this out there because I ran into similar problems with git-svn on a repo that had a long complex branch history (and no standard trunk branch).  Git-svn took a long time because it was trying to determine the start of history traversing backwards.  It took quite a long time, and in the end failed due to problems in this SVN repo's branch history.

What helped make this reliable was to limit the history I cloned to a specific range using `-r  {Rev ID start}..HEAD`.  Perhaps this will help.